# Creating methods with the same attributes

Tags: python, class, methods, instance

I'm creating a code for my game dev. class that needs to create 5 instances of both enemies and regular players. I've gotten it so it creates the 5 instances of one of them, but comes back with `<__main__.Player object at 0x020E3410>` as the other one. They both have the same attributes. My code:

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, nm, am, wp, ht, tp, ide):
        self.name = nm
        self.ammo = am
        self.weapon = wp
        self.health = ht
        self.type = tp
        self.id = ide

class Enemy(object):
    def __init__(self, nm, am, wp, ht, tp, ide):
        self.name = nm
        self.ammo = am
        self.weapon = wp
        self.health = ht
        self.type = tp
        self.id = ide

    def __str__(self):
        values = "Hi my name is " + self.name + "\n" + "Ammo: " + str(self.ammo) + "\n" + "Weapon: " + self.weapon + "\n" + "Health: " + str(self.health) + "\n" + "I am a: " + self.type + "\n" + "ID #: " + str(self.id)
        return values

    def __str__(self):
        values1 = "Hi my name is " + self.name + "\n" + "Ammo: " + str(self.ammo) + "\n" + "Weapon: " + self.weapon + "\n" + "Health: " + str(self.health) + "\n" + "I am a: " + self.type + "\n" + "ID #: " + str(self.id)
        return values1

def main():
    Enemies = 0
    Players = 0
    while Players < 5:
        play1 = (Player("Joe", 5, "Machine gun", 22, "Hero", Players))
        print (play1)
        Players = Players + 1
        break
    while Enemies < 5:
        ene1 = (Enemy("Julian", 100, "Rocket Launcher", 1337, "Enemy", Enemies))
        print (ene1)
        Enemies = Enemies + 1

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Enemy` class has two `__str__` methods, but your `Player` class has none:

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, nm, am, wp, ht, tp, ide):
        self.name = nm
        self.ammo = am
        self.weapon = wp
        self.health = ht
        self.type = tp
        self.id = ide

class Enemy(object):
    def __init__(self, nm, am, wp, ht, tp, ide):
        self.name = nm
        self.ammo = am
        self.weapon = wp
        self.health = ht
        self.type = tp
        self.id = ide

    def __str__(self):
        values = "Hi my name is " + self.name + "\n" + "Ammo: " + str(self.ammo) + "\n" + "Weapon: " + self.weapon + "\n" + "Health: " + str(self.health) + "\n" + "I am a: " + self.type + "\n" + "ID #: " + str(self.id)
        return values

    def __str__(self):
        values1 = "Hi my name is " + self.name + "\n" + "Ammo: " + str(self.ammo) + "\n" + "Weapon: " + self.weapon + "\n" + "Health: " + str(self.health) + "\n" + "I am a: " + self.type + "\n" + "ID #: " + str(self.id)
        return values1
```

You probably want:

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, nm, am, wp, ht, tp, ide):
        self.name = nm
        self.ammo = am
        self.weapon = wp
        self.health = ht
        self.type = tp
        self.id = ide

    def __str__(self):
        values1 = "Hi my name is " + self.name + "\n" + "Ammo: " + str(self.ammo) + "\n" + "Weapon: " + self.weapon + "\n" + "Health: " + str(self.health) + "\n" + "I am a: " + self.type + "\n" + "ID #: " + str(self.id)
        return values1

class Enemy(object):
    def __init__(self, nm, am, wp, ht, tp, ide):
        self.name = nm
        self.ammo = am
        self.weapon = wp
        self.health = ht
        self.type = tp
        self.id = ide

    def __str__(self):
        values = "Hi my name is " + self.name + "\n" + "Ammo: " + str(self.ammo) + "\n" + "Weapon: " + self.weapon + "\n" + "Health: " + str(self.health) + "\n" + "I am a: " + self.type + "\n" + "ID #: " + str(self.id)
        return values
```

Ass a side note, to minimise repeated code you could make a base class like:

```
class BasePlayer(object):
    def __init__(self, nm, am, wp, ht, tp, ide):
        self.name = nm
        self.ammo = am
        self.weapon = wp
        self.health = ht
        self.type = tp
        self.id = ide

    def __str__(self):
        values = "Hi my name is " + self.name + "\n" + "Ammo: " + str(self.ammo) + "\n" + "Weapon: " + self.weapon + "\n" + "Health: " + str(self.health) + "\n" + "I am a: " + self.type + "\n" + "ID #: " + str(self.id)
        return values
```

And then use inheritance to create `Enemy` and `Player`:

```
class Enemy(BasePlayer):
    # enemy related stuff

class Player(BasePlayer):
    # goody related stuff
```